# What entry should be put into the Domain Name, when it comes to SSL Certificates for a Plesk VPS?

Tags: https, security-certificate, vps, plesk

I am currently in the process of securing a VPS of mine, with the *Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate*.

Referring to the below image, was is required, when 'The domain name must resolve to your server'?  Should I enter one of the domains that are on the VPS, in the format of www.domain.com or should I enter the VPS IP Address?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter the exact name used by your visitors. As far as I understand it, the page talks about securing Plesk itself – *not* your actual websites – so naturally it would be the domain name you use for accessing Plesk.

- For example, if you are setting up SSL for `https://plesk.example.com/`, then input `plesk.example.com` in this field.
- If you will be using `https://www.example.com:8443/, then enter`www.example.com`.

(Yes, it has to be a name. Although technically bare IP addresses are possible, most CAs won't issue certificates for them.)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I enter an IP address, in order to access the VPS.  How can I generate/find out its named alternative?

Comment: Buy a domain name. (Or use one you already own.) Make a subdomain for Plesk it you want.

Comment: A sub domain?  Would I then enter the sub domain or the existing IP address when accessing Plesk, in the future?

Comment: If you want to use HTTPS with the new certificate you must use the matching (sub)domain name. If you use plain http, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for your time with your answer.  Ever since obtaining my VPS, only it's IP address was ever communicated; hence my confusion over a VPS Domain name for the Plesk Control Panel, since even my hosting company had to be pushed to reveal its name.

Comment: It doesn't automatically have a name. The VPS company has no requirement or obligation to assign one. You get a server and it's up to you what you do with it.

Comment: My hosting company provided me with the 'VPS Profile', on their website.  The VPS name was assigned and greyed out.  Maybe they had assigned a name, without telling me, and it can only be modified within Plesk and not within the Control Panel, my hosting company provided me.